# JAVA index problems while doing caesar cipher

Tags: java, arrays, string

GOAL OF CODE :(using netbeans)

I was trying to write this code to apply the caesar cipher algorithm where multiple keys can be used in order e.g : key = [1,2,3] , text = test , where it will use key as "1" on "t" then key "2" on "e" then key "3" on "s" then return to key "1" on last t .

OUTPUT :

```
run:
Enter the text : mohammad rahmat
Enter the number of keys you want to use : 3
Enter 3 number of keys : 1
2
3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at caesar.Caesar.main(Caesar.java:68)
nqkbopbfbsckncw
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

CODE :

```
package caesar;    

import java.util.Scanner;    

public class Caesar {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    char table[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
                     'u','v','w','x','y','z',' ','.'};
    String tmp;
    System.out.print("Enter the text : ");
    tmp = input.nextLine();
    char text[] = tmp.toCharArray();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of keys you want to use : ");
    int keyNo = input.nextInt();
    int key[] = new int[keyNo];
    System.out.printf("Enter %d number of keys : ",keyNo);
    for (int i = 0; i < keyNo; ++i){
        key[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    char entext[] = new char[text.length];
    int k = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (k < text.length){
        int j = 0;
        while (text[a] != table[j])
            j++;
        if (key[count]+j >= table.length){
            entext[a] = table[(j+key[count])%table.length];
        }

        else entext[a] = table[j+key[count]];

        a++;
        count++;
        if (count == keyNo)
            count = 0;
        k++;


    }
    String answer = new String(entext);
    System.out.printf("ENCRYPTION : %s \n\n",answer);


    char detext[] = new char[text.length];
    k = 0;
    a = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (k < text.length){
        int j = 0;
        while (text[a] != table[j])
            j++;
        if (key[count]-j < 0){
            detext[a] = table[table.length+(key[count]-j)];
        }

        else detext[a] = table[j-key[count]];

        a++;
        count++;
        if (count == keyNo)
            count = 0;
        k++;


    }
    String answer2 = new String(detext);
    System.out.printf("DECRYPTION : %s\n\n",answer2);
}
}
```

Comment: debug your code with a suitable IDE.. you will get to know the cause..

Comment: @GirlyGirl my question is stated there , i get errors in the build which i cant seem to find out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it finally , while converting it back to original text I had to take the converted text , in other words :

replace

```
while (k < text.length){
    int j = 0;
    while (text[a] != table[j])
```

with

```
while (k < entext.length){
        int j = 0;
        while (entext[a] != table[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a debugger to analyze your code.

```
detext[a] = table[table.length+(key[count]-j)];
```

you're incrementing `j` and subtracting it from `count` which is zero. increment `count` before you operate on finding finding array index.

Comment: u didnt get the pattern there , its key[count] , which can never be zero and theres an if statement so the index will never be negative, at least i think so

Comment: detext[a] = table[j-key[count]];